# A point concerning absolute value of functionals

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, operator-theory, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $M$ be a von Neumann sub-algebra in $B(H)$. Let $\phi$ be a normal functional on $M$. Assume $\psi$ is a normal functional on $B(H)$ with $\psi_{|_M}=\phi$ (note that $\phi$ and $\psi$ may have different norms).

Q. Can we conclude that $|\phi|\leq |\psi|_{|_{M}}$ ?